# How to figure out which action is binded to specific keystroke (keyboard shortcut) in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently I found that (command + ctrl + d) works for dictionary in macOS.

How can I find other keystroke bind to specific action (like finding dictionary)?

I am trying to find the functionality that when I hit the (command + ctrl + d), dictionary appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find all keys this way, but a lot are listed in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

There's no good way to search them, you just have to scroll through the lists until you find the one you want.

[image]